# why is my parameter for doSomething not passing in

Tags: javascript

When i run the code below, the greet function is able to print the parameter l, however the doSomething function is not able to print the parameter h. its just undefined. How can i fix it?

```html
function greet(l) {
    console.log('pringing inside function running ' + l);
}
var g = function doSomething(h) {
    console.log('print inside function doing something' + h);
    return h + 'added';
}
greet('first function');
console.log(g);
console.log('print outside function ' + g.apply('erere'));
//console.log(doSomething('ee'));
```

Comment: `console.log('print outside function ' + g('erere'))`;

Comment: Yes, using `apply` would require you to supply a context first and then an array representing  the arguments to the function.

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) should clear it up. You meant something closer to `g.apply(null, ["abc"])`.